# Creating an instance of a derived class from an instance of the parent class

Tags: c#, derived-class

In general, given a class A, and a derived class DerivedFromA, and an instance of A, is there a way to construct DerivedFromA from that instance?

E.g., let's say that DerivedFromA simply overrides one or more methods or properties of A. Let's say I have some Container class with a CreateA() method that returns an instance of A, and I either can't or don't want to override or otherwise mess with that Container class.  What I want to do is take the instance returned by Container.CreateA(), pass it to a DerivedFromA( A instanceOfA) constructor and have the resulting object be treated just like instanceOfA and  use all of instanceOfA's methods, properties, and data except for the ones I have overridden.

BTW, the language in question is C#, it that makes a difference.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can do this directly. However, you might be able to use something like [Castle DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/) to modify the behaviour

Comment: Every so often (when I'm trying to write something complicated, which luckily isn't often) I try to get my head round what seems like a simple and elegant concept.  It seems like it should be a delegate or a wrapper or adapter pattern but I think you always bump into something that stops you.  (Like methods you can't override or something).   You probably end up "decorating" more instances than you like but I think maybe the closest thing in C# is to use extension methods...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to make a new `DerivedFromA` instance, and use that instance instead of your original.  If you do that, however, it will work fine.

Just add a constructor like you showed:

```
public DerivedFromA(A instanceOfA)
{
    // Copy members from instanceOfA into here as necessary
    this.Foo = instanceOfA.Foo;
    this.Bar = instanceOfA.Bar;

    // Setup unique values
    this.Baz = 42;
}
```

Then, when you call, you can just do:

```
DerivedFromA instance = new DerivedFromA(container.CreateA());
```

Comment: I'm beginning to agree with Rob's comment - you can't do that.  This answer comes the closest, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for, because if the structure of A is subsequently modified, I have to go back and modify DerivedFromA to reflect the new methods, properties, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably make this a new virtual method like so:

```
public class ClassA {
    public virtual string Foo { get; set };

    public virtual ClassA GetAsClassA() {
        return this;
    }
}


public class ClassB : ClassA {
    public virtual string Foo { get; set };

    public override ClassA GetAsClassA() {
        // Create new ClassA and copy properties as needed.
        // Can use base.Foo to get base properties, as needed.
    }
}
```

This wraps up the logic into the classes themselves.