# C++ : Create instance of derived class from instance of parent class without constructor/further knowledge

Tags: c++, derived-class

Same as this : [Creating an instance of a derived class from an instance of the parent class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470929/creating-an-instance-of-a-derived-class-from-an-instance-of-the-parent-class)

Except :

1. C++ (I do not know C#, this was just what the SO research yielded)
2. I do not want to write the list of all parameters that the existing instance has and copy them over. I'd like to do that in one fell swoop, with this code not needing an update when the parent class changes.

In case this is an XY problem : I want to create my own instance of `std::cout` from a derived class of `ostream` that I plan to create, which will have some extra methods and also overridden operators that will allow me to do more things, among which the ability to elsewhere mute the output, all code passing data to `cout` staying the same.

E.g. `mutableCout << someData << "," << someData;` stays the same but elsewhere I can write `mutableCout.mute()`

But I am generally interested in this question, as far as C++ is concerned.

***Is it feasible in C++ ?***

I expect it would look something like this :

```
class A
{
    A(<...>);

    SomeTypeA m_a;
    SomeTypeB m_b;
    .
    .
    .
    SomeTypeZ m_z;
}

class B : public A
{
public:
    B(A instanceOfA, someValueB)
    {
        <...copy everything from instanceOfA...>;

        valueB = someValueB;
    }
    void set() {valueB = true};
    void unset() {valueB = false};

private:
    bool valueB;
}

extern A instanceOfA;

B instanceOfB = B(instanceOfA, false);
...
instanceOfB.set();
```

The part that says `<...copy everything from instanceOfA...>` is the one I want to discuss, if at all feasible. I do not want to write :

```
m_a = instanceOfA.m_a
m_b = instanceOfA.m_b
....
m_z = instanceOfA.m_z
```

***Question : Is it feasible in C++ ?***

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256346/discussion-on-question-by-charles-c-create-instance-of-derived-class-from-in); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

If we ignore the fact that you're planning to do this to `std::cout`, in your specific example you could do this:

```
B(A a) : A(std::move(a)) // `move` is optional
{
    // ...
}
```

Or this: (slightly less optimal, but is usable outside of consturctors of `B`)

```
B(A a)
{
    A::operator=(std::move(a)); // `move` is optional
    // ...
}
```

---

But if your goal is to customize the behavior of `std::cout`, this is not the best option. The state of `std::cout` is not copyable, a better option would be to create your own independent `std::ostream`.

Or, *even better* option would be to forget about output streams. C++20 `std::format` is most likely the future of text output. Consider creating your own function wrapping `std::format` and printing the result.